# Template could not be loaded in TYPO3 extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Am using a new extension build in TYPO3 V4.5.0 and after it installed it in TYPO3 V6.2.x it shows the following error

```
The template files "/var/www/dev/typo3/typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Resources/Private/Layouts/Suche.html", "/var/www/dev/typo3/typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Resources/Private/Layouts/Suche" could not be loaded.
```

The layout i s present in the location. and path given also correct in backend..
How can i fix this?

Comment: Check so template filename has first letter uppercase?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt  Ooopss !!.. you are right... I dint noticed that.. Thank you so much for ur ans and fast response. :)

Comment: No problem, stumbled upon this some times myself. :) It's enforced in TYPO3 6 but not before, don't know why. :P

Comment: @OlleHärstedt It wasted my time a lot.. I tried checking the path and all.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt, write the answer so we can upvote, just FYI, it's rather matter of the system's case-sensitive abbilities, anyway best approach is to use always CamelCase names as TYPO3 looks for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check so template filename has first letter uppercase.

The rule is that for action named `fooBarAction()` template file must be named `FooBar.html`

Comment: Thank you.It was the mistake I made